# How to solve for a constant

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm totally stuck at those equations:

> $a+b=5$
>      $ax+b=11$
>      $a+bx=9$

I need to solve for $x$.

I know this is embarrassing but maybe someone can give me a clue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the second and third equation. We get
$$(a+b)x + (a+b) = 20$$
From the first equation, we have $a+b = 5$. Hence, we get $x = \ldots$

> Since $a+b = 5$, we get $5x + 5 = 20 \implies 5x = 15 \implies x = 3$.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the fast help. I had a similar idea but somehow my brain was stuck...

Comment: And we can also solve the equation for a and b.

a = 3, b = 2

Answer (score 2):

Try to take the sum of two last lines, then extract a factor $(a+b)$ on the left.